# doubt was raised and doubt had raised

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

"A doubt had raised in the mind of passenger because of some sound, before he ask to stop the bus"

Is above sentence construction is correct?
Is it correct to use *a doubt was raised* in above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

*Raise* is a transitive verb, requiring a Direct Object, so *A doubt had raised* won't work. You could use the related intransitive *arose*:

> A doubt arose in the passenger's mind . . .

Passive *A doubt **was** raised* is acceptable grammatically, but it doesn't fit well with your *because* phrase: the Agent, the entity which performs the act, is usually indicated with a *by* phrase in the passive:

> A doubt was raised . . . **by** some sound . . .

Me, I'd cast it in the active voice:

> Some sound raised a doubt in the passenger's mind . . .